# List problem in Reporting Services 2005

Tags: list, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a problem with a list in srss 2005.
The list is grouping too much information and I dont know how to un-group it. I made a picture to show it. But because I'm new, I can only show it with this link: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6058/listproblem.gif

So the list is also grouping the weeks, but that is not what I would like.
Does anyone know how to change this? (in the designer view)

Thanks in advance,

Kris

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using a subreport